# FSP influence over kerberos token size

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

We have a 2 way trust between our 2 forest. There are some users from forest A that are in group in forest B - they are listed by sid in foreign security principals OU. I checked membership of one of such user and the group from another forest is not listed in his memberOf attribute.

Question: will this group have an influence over kerberos token size?